# PHP uploading an image

Tags: php, image, upload

I am struggling to get PHP to process a posted image. The code which supposedly gets the tempory link is here:

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES["pic"]["name"]);
```

But I get the error

> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty

The image is definatly being posted as running this:

```
echo $_POST['pic'];
```

prints the name of the image.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here? The field name from the form is *pic*.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

The image is then meant to be uploaded to Imgur.

EDIT:

HTMl included for reference:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="additem" role="form" method="POST" action="add.php">
  <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Photos will be uploaded to <a href="http://imgur.com">imgur</a></div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="dept">Department</label>
      <select class="form-control" name="dept" id="dept">
      <option>Options...</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pic">Image link</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" id="pic" name="pic"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How can you use $_POST Array instead of $_FILES for image manipulation?

Comment: Why are you closing the input tags? </input>

Comment: Becuase I didn't realise they were self closing!

Comment: if(!empty($_FILES["pic"]["name"]))
{$file=$_FILES["pic"]["name"];
$getc=file_get_contants($file);
echo $getc;}?

Comment: Well, there is no need to close the input tag if your doctype is html5

Comment: @CodingHorror what does the code you posted do? I didn't know that!

Comment: I added a conditional statement to check if the posted file is empty or not,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix:

A combination of adding the enctype to the form and adding a DOCTYPE to the markup fixed the issue.

Thanks to all who helped

Answer (score 0):

According to the [relevant comment in documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#89674), the files are *temporarily* being stored somewhere in your system. `name` is only a string, though.

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES["pic"]['tmp_name']);
```

Just out of curiosity: did you set `type='file'` on your `input` control?

Comment: It just gives me the same error; empty filename and yes I did.

Comment: Could you expand @jquery-php-magento-com

Answer (score 0):

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['pic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$filename = "./your-image.$ext";
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'], $filename)) {
    $file = file_get_contents($filename);
}
```

Comment: I only need to get the adress...I think! That looks to be moving the image? I am not 'uploading' it to my sevrer, the image is then sent to Imgur.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [PHP docs (Handling file uploads)](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), you probably want to access the file's content, not the filename. Therefore, you need to use:

```
$filecontents = file_get_contents($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']).
```

Answer (score -1):

To upload a file, you need to add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

as an attribute to the form tag.
Refer: [PHP 5 File Upload](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)